# Airport simulation in JavaScript with a fixed number of aircraft waiting to takeoff and land

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simplified airport simulator in JavaScript with very simple CSS or JQuery animation to demonstrate a takeoff or a landing (such as an image disappearing on takeoff or landing). There is already a predetermined number of 5 aircraft (callsign represents aircraft)  on the takeoff queue and 5 aircraft on a landing queue. Here is how i have started it

```
function airport() 
    {
        this.takeoff_queue = ["KQA","ERJ","TOM","DHL","ETH"];
        this.landing_queue = ["RWA","KLM","PAN","FLY540","JAMBO"];
        this.arrival = function arrival()
        this.departure = function departure()
```

Since there is one runway. The landing aircraft should have priority when both arrival and departure times are the same. I am assuming that there is a takeoff every 1 minute and a landing every 2 minutes. I plan on using the arrival and departure functions to dequeue each queue using the Array `shift()` method.

For every dequeue, i should also animate very simply by making one of several images in html divs representing the queued aircraft dissolve or delete. The Big question is how should i go about implementing a timing feature to run the simulation and give priority to arrivals when need be? Also, how can i incorporate the image animation?

Comment: Have you written anything yet?

Comment: Not yet. I am studying for an Interview so i need to learn so much in a short time especially since am new at OOP in JavaScript. being able to tackle this will teach a lot in a short time i hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript provides two timings functions :

1. setTimeout(function, interval)
2. setInterval(function, interval)

Have a look at the functions and how they can be used. And especially the difference between the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the use-case, so i worked-out a simulation (just for fun). I hope you are not a student and i am wasting your assignment now.

http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/398oezj0/13/

```js
function AirPlane() {
    this.state = ko.observable();
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.destination = ko.observable();
    this.location = ko.observable();
    this.arrivesOn = ko.observable();
    this.takeOfftime = ko.observable();
    this.startTime = null;

    // set take off state
    this.takeOff = function (runWay) {
        this.runWay = runWay;
        this.state("Taking off");
        this.takeOfftime(60);
    }

    // set the destination
    this.setDestination = function (name, time) {
        this.startTime = time;
        this.arrivesOn(time);
        this.state("Flying");
        this.destination(name);
    }

    // calculate an airplane number
    var n = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 1000).toString();
    while (n.length < 4) {
        n = "0" + n;
    }

    // computed for the progress bar
    this.progress = ko.computed(function () {
        if (this.state() == "Flying" || this.state() == "Landing") {
            
            if (this.arrivesOn()) {
                return Math.floor(100 - ((this.startTime - this.arrivesOn()) / this.startTime) * 100).toString() + "%"
            }
        } else if (this.state() == "Taking off" && this.takeOfftime()) {
            return Math.floor(100 - ((60 - this.takeOfftime()) / 60) * 100).toString() + "%"
        }

        return null;

    }, this);
    
    this.name("PH" + n);
    
    // airplane clock, manages arriveal, landing and takingOff
    this.tick = function () {
        if (this.arrivesOn()) {
            this.arrivesOn(this.arrivesOn() - 1);

            if (this.state() == "Flying") {

                if (this.arrivesOn() < 60) {
                    this.state("Landing");
                }
            } else if (this.state() == "Landing") {

                if (this.arrivesOn() <= 0) {
                    this.state("Landed")
                    this.location("schiphol");
                    this.destination("");
                    this.arrivesOn(null)
                }
            }
        }


        if (this.takeOfftime()) {
            this.takeOfftime(this.takeOfftime() - 1);
            if (this.takeOfftime() <= 0) {
                this.state("Flying");
                this.destination("Far Far away");
                this.runWay.state("Free");
                this.location("");
                this.arrivesOn(null);
                this.runWay = null;
                this.takeOfftime(null);
            }
        }
    }
}

// for the future, when we have multiple runways :-)
function RunWay() {
    this.state = ko.observable("Free");
}

// Airfield object, future use, if we want to simulate multiple airfields
function AirField(world) {

    this.world = world;
    this.name = "schiphol";
    this.runWay = new RunWay();

    // finds the first free runway, we have one, so easy
    this.getFreeRunway = function () {
        if (this.runWay.state() == "Free") {
            return this.runWay;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    // finds the first plane that is due to arrive, this includes planes in the landing state
    this.getNextArrival = function () {
        var arrivalOn;
        var arrivalPlane;
        var _this = this;

        this.world.airPlanes().forEach(function (ap) {
            if (
            (ap.state() == "Flying" || ap.state() == "Landing") && ap.destination() == _this.name) {
                if (!arrivalPlane) {
                    arrivalPlane = ap;
                    arrivalOn = ap.arrivesOn();
                } else if (ap.arrivesOn() < arrivalOn) {
                    arrivalPlane = ap;
                    arrivalOn = ap.arrivesOn();
                }
            }
        });

        return arrivalPlane;
    }

    // Finds a waiting airplane that is ready to depart, it must be on this airfield (duh)
    this.getWaitingAirPlane = function () {
        var _this = this;
        var returnValue;
        this.world.airPlanes().forEach(function (ap) {
            if (!returnValue && ap.state() == "Waiting" && ap.location() == _this.name) {
                returnValue = ap;
            }
        });

        return returnValue;
    }

    // try to schedule a tack off
    // Check if we have 60s free before a plan STARTS landing == arrivesOn -60
    // if we have that slot, the plane can takeof
    this.scheduleTakeOff = function () {
        var nextArrival = this.getNextArrival();
        var freeRunway = this.getFreeRunway();
        var waitingPlane = this.getWaitingAirPlane();

        var landingOn = nextArrival.arrivesOn() - 60;

        if (freeRunway && landingOn > 60) {
            debugger;
            if (waitingPlane) {
                freeRunway.state("Occupied");
                waitingPlane.takeOff(freeRunway);
            }

        }
    }
}

// World simulation
function World() {
    this.airPlanes = ko.observableArray();
    this.airField = new AirField(this);
    
    // the ticking clock
    this.time = ko.observable(0);
    var airPlane;

    // load 10 waiting planes
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        airPlane = new AirPlane();
        airPlane.airField = this.airField;
        airPlane.state("Waiting");
        airPlane.location("schiphol");
        this.airPlanes.push(airPlane);
    }

    // load 10 flying planes, they arrive 120s after each other with 60s random to make things more interesting
    var arrivalTime = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        airPlane = new AirPlane();
        var arrivalTime = arrivalTime + 120 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
        airPlane.setDestination("schiphol", arrivalTime);
        this.airPlanes.push(airPlane);

    }

    // run the simulation
    this.tick = function () {
        this.time(this.time() + 1);
        var _this = this;

        // update plane progress
        this.airPlanes().forEach(function (ap) {
            ap.tick();
        });

        // try to schedule a tack off
        this.airField.scheduleTakeOff();

        // play with the 100ms here to speedup or slow down
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            _this.tick();
        }, 100);
    }



}

// bind the world
var world = new World();

// start the clock
world.tick();
ko.applyBindings(world);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<strong>Time:<span data-bind="text:time"></span></strong>

<br/>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>state</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Arrives/TakesOff</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:airPlanes">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:state"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:location"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:destination"></td>
 
            <td class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="height:100%;" data-bind="style: { 'width': progress }, css:{ 'progress-bar-danger': (state()=='Taking off' || state()=='Landing'), 'progress-bar-success':state()=='Flying' }">
                    <span data-bind="text:arrivesOn"></span> <span data-bind="text:takeOfftime"></span>

                </div>
            </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code is very informative. i however don't understand how you implemented the whole timing of takeoffs and landings. Care to explain that a bit? If possible a pseudocode would be of great help

Comment: An airplane is an object.

Comment: Yes i do understand that. My question regards how to implement timing as you have done. i do not understand how you initiated the landing and takeoff sequence and enabling the landing to take priority when both landing and takeoff times are the same. Is my question clear sir?

Comment: A simplified fiddle with only the "Arrival countdown logic" (http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/ba9g9kh1/1/) .  Basically the airplane is an object with a state `arrivesOn`. The heart of the simulation, The `World` object has a `tick` method that is called every 100ms using a `setTimeout` call. This `tick` method manages the next step in the world by calling  `tick` in every airplane object so the airplane can update its arrival time. 

Please review `scheduleTakeOff` function. That is finding the arrival time of the next plane and checks if it is possible to takeof the next plane.

Comment: Yeah. I see your point. Thanks a lot for the help.